# easeljs bitmapanimation auto stop on last frame

Tags: html, easeljs

```
var antAnimationData = {
            images: ["images/ants.png"],
        frames: [

            [2, 2, 85, 121], 
            [89, 2, 85, 121], 
            [176, 2, 85, 121], 
            [263, 2, 85, 121], 
            [350, 2, 85, 121], 
            [2, 125, 85, 121], 
            [89, 125, 85, 121], 
            [176, 125, 85, 121], 
            [263, 125, 85, 121], 
            [350, 125, 85, 121], 
            [2, 248, 85, 121], 
            [89, 248, 85, 121], 
            [176, 248, 85, 121], 
            [263, 248, 85, 121], 
            [350, 248, 85, 121]
        ],
        animations: {

                show: { frames: [1,3,5,7,9,11,14], next: false, frequency: 1 }
        }
    };

antsAnimationSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(antAnimationData);
```

i am using easeljs sprite sheet animation like that, i have tried a few alternatives but my animation does not stop on last frame when played, it keeps repeating, i want it such a way that if i run that animation, it should automatically stop on last frame of that animation.

Comment: looks good to me, what version of EaselJS are you using? can you maybe post the part with the `gotoAndPlay('show')`? maybe you are calling that repeatedly?

Comment: i am using animation.play(); should i use gotoAndPlay() ?

Comment: thanks, it works now. the only diffrence was me using play instead of gotoAndPlay

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `play()` just repeats ALL frames, if you haven't set a specific animation before (in your case `show`), if you have set and animation before you can use `.stop()` and `.play()` to pause/continue the animation.

Comment: ps.: you can put an answer below and accept it, so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

comment provided by olsn

looks good to me, what version of EaselJS are you using? can you maybe post the part with the gotoAndPlay('show')? maybe you are calling that repeatedly?

solved it